# Fortinet FortiGate logs re not getting inserted in elastic search using fleet integration

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone please assist me, what all settings I can cross check at fortinet side to ensure that syslog matches Fortinet FortiGate logs integration requirement?

Current status:
Integration and all required assets are installed in kiana.
No error and warn noticed in elastic agent logs.

OLD question:
Could you please assist me on how I can add RFC3164 version to
logs-fortinet.firewall-1.7.2 ingest pipeline?

ALso, is it possible to add RFC3103 (using syslog_pri filter or kv filter) if yes, please assist with some examples to parse data?

[image]

Comment: Can you show your grok processor?

Comment: Do you mean the pattern list fetched by running GET _ingest/processor/grok ? I doubt I can share it, as it is quite big.

Comment: I mean how your grok processor inside you ingest pipeline is defined

Comment: {
    "grok": {
      "field": "event.original",
      "patterns": [
        "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{GREEDYDATA:syslog5424_sd}$"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "kv": {
      "field": "syslog5424_sd",
      "field_split": " (?=[a-z\\_\\-]+=)",
      "value_split": "=",
      "prefix": "fortinet.firewall.",
      "ignore_missing": true,
      "ignore_failure": false,
      "trim_value": "\""
    }
  }.....

Comment: Please update your question, it's more legible than in comments

Comment: Also, now we upgraded the fortinet firmware version to v6.4.10, so that syslogs will follow the RFC5424, but still no luck. No data is getting inserted in elasticsearch from logs-fortinet_fortigate integration.

Comment: Hi Niveditak. Now that the firmware is in the supported version, I would revert the pipeline to the one provided by Elastic. In my understanding you tried to add support for the RFC3164 with a non-existent grok filter. So please revert the pipeline to the default one and retry

Comment: All changes are reverted back, however still no data is getting inserted in elastic. I am trying to figure out the syslog format currently set in Fortinet, as it can be set to default rather than RCF. I will update the question. Thanks